# last.fm - get top fans for artist

Tags: python, last.fm

I'm trying to retrieve `top fans` for a given artist on `last.fm` `API`.

I build the call with:

```
last = pylast.LastFMNetwork(api_key = API_KEY, api_secret =API_SECRET, username = username, password_hash = password_hash)

art = last.get_artist(artist)

fans  = art.get_top_fans(limit=2)
```

but I am getting the following error:

`pylast.WSError: Invalid Method - No method with that name in this package`

has this method been deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last.fm API methods are listed here:

http://www.last.fm/api

Artists do not appear to have a getTopFans method, so that is likely causing your issue.

Comment: yes I know the documentation, but the wrapper -please refer to `https://github.com/pylast/pylast/blob/develop/tests/test_pylast.py`, lists the `get_top_fans` method on `line 1252`. that's why I ask if it has been deprecated.

Comment: The plastic library has not been updated since 2014 and there have been significant changes to the last.fm API since then.  So while there is indeed a get_last_fans method defined in the library, it cannot be used as there is no corresponding API endpoint.